# HTML select form with option to search the dropdown list

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

```
 <input type="text" list="cars" />
<datalist id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</datalist>
```

**In the code above I would want to limit the users strictly to the options in datalist and prevent him/her from entering custom values.** I cannot use **select** because the list is very long and fetaures of **datalist** like auto suggestion is really helpful.

Comment: can you please explain what's the issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using JQuery? What you are trying to achive can easily be done like this

```
<input type="text" list="cars" id='disableTyping' />
<datalist id="cars">
<option>Volvo</option>
<option>Saab</option>
<option>Mercedes</option>
<option>Audi</option>
</datalist>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#disableTyping').keypress(function(e) {
    return false;
});
</script>
```

And also if you decide to use this approach make sure to include JQuery in the `<head></head>` of your page.